# Getting error : "could not determine kind of name for C.functionName()" with cgo

Tags: c++, c, go, linker, cgo

I am trying to wrap, C++ library using Go. Here I have a header file and a CPP file and I have written a wrapper for it in Go and trying to call the, but I get the error :

```
could not determine the kind of name for C.getName
could not determine kind of name for C.reset
```

All three files are in the same directory and the command used from the directory is :

> ****go build CountersImpl.go****
>
> Other Details : Windows 10-64, Using Vscode, go version: 1.16.4

A few lines from the files with filename
**CountersImpl.h**

```
#ifndef SRC_HOTROD_API_COUNTERSIMPL_H_
#define SRC_HOTROD_API_COUNTERSIMPL_H_

#ifdef __cplusplus
#include "infinispan\hotrod\CounterConfiguration.h"
#include "hotrod\impl\RemoteCounterManagerImpl.h"
#include <string>
#include <future>
extern "C" {
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
namespace infinispan {
namespace hotrod {

class BaseCounterImpl: public virtual Counter {
public:
    BaseCounterImpl(RemoteCounterManagerImpl& rcm, std::string name, CounterConfiguration configuration) :
            rcm(rcm), name(name), configuration(configuration), removed(false) {
    }

    std::string getName() {
        return name;
    }
    CounterConfiguration getConfiguration() {
        return configuration;
    }

    void setRemoved() {
        removed = true;
    }

    void reset();

    void remove();

    virtual long getValue();

    const void* addListener(const event::CounterListener* listener);

    void removeListener(const void* handler);

    virtual ~BaseCounterImpl() {
    }
```

**CountersImpl.cpp**

```
#include <hotrod\api\CountersImpl.h>
#include "hotrod\impl\operations\CounterOperations.h"

namespace infinispan {
namespace hotrod {

using namespace infinispan::hotrod::operations;

void BaseCounterImpl::reset() {
    ResetCounterOperation op(*rcm.codec, rcm.transportFactory, rcm.topology, 0, name);
    op.execute();
}

void BaseCounterImpl::remove() {
    RemoveCounterOperation op(*rcm.codec, rcm.transportFactory, rcm.topology, 0, name);
    op.execute();
    setRemoved();
}

long BaseCounterImpl::getValue() {
    GetCounterValueOperation op(*rcm.codec, rcm.transportFactory, rcm.topology, 0, name);
    return op.execute();
}
```

**CountersImpl.go**

```
package CountersImpl

// #include "CountersImpl.h"
import "C"
import "fmt"
func main() {

    fmt.Println("name : ",C.getName())
    C.reset()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`cgo` only understands C, not C++. The `#ifdef __cplusplus` directives in your `.h` file remove its contents when building the file as an ordinary C source file.

Moreover, the C++ methods `infinispan::hotrod::BaseCounterImpl::getName` and `infinispan::hotrod::BaseCounterImpl::reset` are not C function names. A `BaseCounterImpl` method must be called on a `BaseCounterImpl` object, and C doesn't know anything about objects.

To call a C++ method from C, you generally need to define a corresponding C wrapper function that accepts a pointer to the `this` object. See https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp for more detail.

---

Once you have a wrapper that can call the needed C++ functions from C, then you can use `cgo` to invoke the C wrapper function from Go.